# Перевыделение памяти с++, такое возможно?

Tags: c++

Недавно задали лабораторную домой по с++. Перерыл почти весь интернет но ответ на один вопрос так и не нашёл.

**Условие:** у меня есть односвязный список, в нем несколько информационных полей. Есть поле "ИМЯ" с динамически выделенной памятью, вот с ним и проблема: нужно разрешить пользователю изменить его тип на `[char/int/float/double]`. Это вроде не сложно, а вот вторая часть меня просто убила: нужно разрешить пользователю изменять количество байт, которые были выделены ранее. Такое вообще возможно осуществить?

Comment: "Перерыл почти весь интернет но ответ на один вопрос так и не нашёл" - два варианта: или Вы задавали неверные ключевые слова  в поисковике, или ответа действительно нету. Какие ключевые слова были использованы?

Comment: [man realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Comment: Во-первых, каким это образом вам удалось разрешить *пользователю* изменять тип поля - ума не приложу ("Это вроде не сложно"... Правда???). Во-вторых, каким образом "изменяется количество байт" критически зависит от того, каким образом они "были выделены ранее". У вас же об этом - ни слова.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы воспользовался такой штукой, как [`any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) или (как я подозреваю, именно это требуется) объединением (`union`). Конечно, нужно тягать дополнительное поле типа etc. Это - если бы была только первая часть задания (менять тип поля).

Судя по второй части - менять размер - мне кажется, что от вас ждут поля типа `void*`, или `char*`, память для которого выделяется как `new char[size]`, а потом используется приведение к нужному типу (ценителей чистоты strict alias прошу не беспокоиться :)). Сложно, многословно, непонятно, зачем - но задания преподов часто необъяснимы :)

Т.е. что-то вроде

```
enum types { INT, CHAR, .... };
void * p = new char[sizeof(int)];
types t = INT;

// Работаем с *(int*)p как с int (см. значение t)

// Переключение на double
delete[]p;
p = new char[sizeof(double)];
t = DOUBLE;
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Если предлагаете `any`, то вместо `union` логично предложить `variant`, как сущность, которую гораздо проще использовать.

Comment: @ixSci Соглашусь - потому что ни тот, ни другой практически не использовал, и сказать, что проще в работе - не могу, полагаюсь на вас.